# xlop package controlling resultstyle when style=text

Tags: equations, xlop

Does `xlop` support `resultstyle` when style is set to text. If it does not is there a way to hide the result with style set to text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}


\opadd[style=text,resultstyle=\color{white}]{1}{2}


\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resultstyle` key has no effect in text style. I can offer you a patch to `\op@textoperation` that does the job in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newif\ifshowresult
\newcommand{\showornot}[1]{%
  \ifshowresult#1\else\phantom{#1}\fi
}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\op@textoperation}{\Op@@r}{\showornot{\Op@@r}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\opadd[style=text]{1}{2}X

\showresulttrue
X\opadd[style=text]{1}{2}X

\end{document}​
```

The `X`'s are there to show that the space for the result is left.

[image]